# Domain of a Piecewise Function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've got a piecewise function defined as :

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
|2x-1| & x<1\\
x^2-1 & 1 \le x <2\\
\lfloor 3x \rfloor & x \in [2,3)
\end{cases}
$$

I am trying to find the domain of this function and I haven't been able to find a like example but I believe the domain of this function is just (-∞,3) from reading off from the values but this is incorrect.

If the domain is all possible x values that can be put into f(x) I am unsure how this answer is wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: your answer looks valid to me. Have you forgot some details in your post? What should be the "correct" answer?

Comment: I am not sure. The question does state find the domain of f using intervals or union of intervals using standard bracket notation which I believe I have done.

Comment: Your domain is right.

Comment: @Michael could you post the supposedly correct answer?

Comment: I unfortunately do not have the correct answer. I have spent the best part of today researching domains and domains of piecewise functions but I cannot come up with a different answer other than my origin which is wrong.

Comment: @Michael Why are you so convinced that your answer is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned in comments, your domain is correct. That is, for your piecewise-defined function $f$ you have $\operatorname{Dom}(f)=(-\infty,3)$. However, perhaps you meant to determine the *range* of $f$ instead. If so, then you should be able to see that $\operatorname{Rng}(f)=[0,\infty)$. If you are certain that your book means domain instead of range, then you must accept the fact that your book is simply wrong (this would not be the first time a math book had a misprint or misinformation).

Comment: Thanks yeah you're probably right the next question in my tutorial was the range I did get [0,∞) for. Thanks for all the comments.